# Finding median of an array with C

Tags: c, arrays, function, return

I need to write a function `int median(int d[], int size)` in C that finds the median of an array. The function needs to call a function `void selectsort(int d[], int size)` that sorts the array for the `median()` function. Only the `median()` function is allowed to call the `selectsort()` function.

How can I get the sorted array from `selectsort()` to `median()` if I need to use a `void` return type? I though about using a pointer, but that also doesn't work because the pointer would need to be returned as well. I cannot nest `selectsort()` within `median()`.

Comment: Why doesn't the pointer workout to sort the original array on which the `median` function would work?

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.  It is a very reasonable (if fairly junior) question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass a non-const pointer to a function, you let that function modify the content to which the pointer points. So the solution in your case is to pass the same pointer to both functions:

```
int data[] = {1,11,2,12,3,13,4,14};
// Sort the data array
selectsort(data, 8);
// Find the median of the same data array
int m = median(data, size);
```

> Only median() is allowed to call selectsort()

If that is the case, and assuming that you would like to keep the original ordering in place, you could make a copy of your array like this:

```
int median(int d[], int size) {
    int *data = malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
    memcpy(data, d, sizeof(int)*size));
    selectsort(data, 8);
    // Use data to find median
    int med = ...
    free(data);
    return med;
}
```

The idea is to preserve the content of the original array by sorting its copy.

Comment: I'm still fairly new to C, so a couple follow-up questions, if I may. `data` is a pointer to the memory location of the array data, correct? If that's true, then I can pass a pointer to an array as a parameter as `d[]`, sort using it as a normal array in `selectsort()`, then call the pointer back in `median()` which will reference the now-sorted array?

Comment: @StevenH Yes, exactly. Meantime, the `d` array passed from the caller of `median()` would remain unchanged, because you never write to it.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, and was exactly what I needed to understand what's going on. Thank you!

Comment: One more question: Why is 8 passed to `selectsort()`? Shouldn't `size` be passed?

Comment: @StevenH Absolutely! That's what happens when I copy/paste :-(

Answer (score 3):

Presumably `selectsort` sorts the array in place, destroying the original ordering.

Simply pass `d` to `median` after calling `selectsort`.

Comment: I apologize, I did not specify in my original post (now clarified): Only `median()` is allowed to call `selectsort()`. I cannot call `selectsort()` itself, so I wouldn't be able to pass `d` back to `median()` without a return type. I'm not terribly familiar with memory processes in C, however, so this may not be what you're saying at all.

Comment: In C you are passing a pointer to the original array `d` to the functions `median()` and `selectsort()`. The array `d` will be modified and you can traverse it to find the median. No return value is required from `selectsort()`

Answer (score 1):

[Selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) is an 'in place' sorting algorithm. That means, that if you pass in the array to selectsort(), it will use that array as the working memory, and it will be sorted when the function returns.